# CSS - How do I style a select to fully occupy the td it is in

Tags: css

This is a simplified version of an html table I have:
(The table is RTL)

```
......
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>A New Think Pad</option>
            <option>OptB</option>
            <option>OptC</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>    .....
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>Poker</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that it ends out looking something like this:

[image]

How do i get the option below (Poker) to size itself to the size of the td.
(I do not know the size of the td in advance)

I have tried:

```
select, option { width:inherit;}
```

But it does not seem to do the job.

Thanks in advance and be happy, Julian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
select { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much - my head seems to be connected backwards today. I will approve the answer in a few minutes - I just found out that you have to wait 7 minutes before you can approve an answer. By the way welcome to SO.